# How to get a particular property of one JSON using one common property with other JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-2017

I am new to react.js and facing problems while performing the below task.

When running following the code, it shows `setState` can't be used and the app breaks. I have these two objects, `obj2` generates a table `3 columns`. I need to make each cell of `definition` column which are not `null` clickable which then land me to the `team_wiki` link which is present in `obj1`.

```
obj1: {
    providers : [
         {team_name : "XYZ", team_wiki : "https://example.com", team_id : 1},
         {team_name : "ABC", team_wiki : "null", team_id : 2},
         {team_name : "LMN", team_wiki : "https://example2.com", team_id : 3},
         {team_name : "MNO", team_wiki : "https://example3.com", team_id : 4}
    ]
}

obj2: {
    products : [
       {team_name : "XYZ", definition : "this team handles XYZ products", metric_id : 101},
       {team_name : "ABC", definition : "this team handles ABC products", metric_id : 201},
       {team_name : "LMN", definition : "this team handles LMN products", metric_id : 301},
       {team_name : "MNO", definition : "this team handles MNO products", metric_id : 401}
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
state = {
    API_DATA : {},
    TEAM_WIKI : ''
}

componentDidMount(){
   // fetch the obj1 data and sets it to the state called API_DATA
}

wikiLink = (TEAM_NAME) {
   // getting TEAM_NAME from a component inside the render method
   const wiki = this.state.API_DATA.map(provider => {
       if (provider.team_name = TEAM_NAME && provider.team_wiki !== null) {
           return provider.team_wiki
       }
   })
   .map(link => {
       if (link !== undefined) {
           return link
       }
   })

   this.setState({
      // TEAM_WIKI is a state { its a string } where i want to store the 
      //team_wiki at last
      TEAM_WIKI : wiki
   })
}

render() {

   return (
         // i want to use it something like this
        < href="this.state.TEAM_WIKI" onClick={this.wikiLink(TEAM_NAME)} />
   ) 
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting back from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels to me that when the first ever render happens, `this.wikiLink` is being *called*, not *passed as reference*. Why do I think so? Because I see round brackets there. The body of this method contains a call to `this.setState`, which means the state of the component is being swapped on render time, and it is a violation of component lifecycle.

Consider a case:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonClicked: false,
    };
    this.handleClickButton = this.handleClickButton.bind(this);
  }

  handleClickButton() {
    this.setState({
      buttonClicked: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClickButton()}>click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

There is a problem! The expression `this.handleClickButton()` is a function call. Within it, there is a state change instruction. When the code is trying to do that, React shows a warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition 
>   (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods 
>    should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, 
>    but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

What we really want instead is to call the function `this.handleClickButton` on button click. To do so, we need to pass a reference to this function to the `onClick` prop, like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClickButton}>click me</button>
    );
  }
```

notice the absence of round brackets.

So what should you do then?

There are two options:

### Option 1: anonymous function inside onClick

Instead of writing

```
render() {
   return (
     // i want to use it something like this
     <a href="this.state.TEAM_WIKI" onClick={this.wikiLink(TEAM_NAME)} />
   );
}
```

do

```
render() {
   return (
     // i want to use it something like this
     <a href="this.state.TEAM_WIKI" onClick={() => this.wikiLink(TEAM_NAME)} />
   );
}
```

This way, a reference to an anonymous function declared in-place is passed per each call to `render` method of the component instance. This function is then going to be called at some unpredictable point in time when the user decides to click, that is, dispatch the MouseEvent of type "click".

### Option 2: make this.wikiLink(•) return a function!

The concept of function returning a function is often referred to as partial application or, in cases similar to this more often, a *closure*. So the `wikiLink` function would then instead of this:

```
wikiLink(TEAM_NAME) {
  // getting TEAM_NAME from a component inside the render method
  const wiki = this.state.API_DATA.map(provider => {
    if ((provider.team_name = TEAM_NAME && provider.team_wiki !== null)) {
      return provider.team_wiki;
    }
  }).map(link => {
    if (link !== undefined) {
      return link;
    }
  });

  this.setState({
    // TEAM_WIKI is a state { its a string } where i want to store the
    //team_wiki at last
    TEAM_WIKI: wiki
  });
}
```

look like this:

```
wikiLink(TEAM_NAME) {
  return () => {
    // getting TEAM_NAME from a component inside the render method
    const wiki = this.state.API_DATA.map(provider => {
      if ((provider.team_name = TEAM_NAME && provider.team_wiki !== null)) {
        return provider.team_wiki;
      }
    }).map(link => {
      if (link !== undefined) {
        return link;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      // TEAM_WIKI is a state { its a string } where i want to store the
      //team_wiki at last
      TEAM_WIKI: wiki
    });
  };
}
```

So that when it is called, it returns a new function. Because `onClick` prop is expected to receive a function, we solve the problem of type matching. Because we call `wikiLink` with some argument `TEAM_NAME` and this argument is being applied every time that function is executed, we solve the problem of retaining context. Isn't this awesome!

---

To get a better idea of using a function that returns a function, check out [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6zj3p48z1k), lines 16 to 23. Hope it will give some idea of how to leverage closures in situations when you need to manage state of a React component.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, it was really helpful. it solved the issue. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The function `wikiLink` is not a class function and not binded to your component. You can either use es6 syntax to bind wikiLink or you bind `wikiLink` to your component.

Either make `wikiLink` something like

```
wikiLink = (TEAM_NAME) => { // rest of your code
```

OR:
in your `constructor` you do something like

```
constructor(){
this.wikiLink = this.wikiLink.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Why would assigning `wikiLink = (TEAM_NAME)` make sense?

Comment: We are not assigning `TEAM_NAME` to `wikiLink`. It's just another way of defining a function. `TEAM_NAME` still remains arguments passed into the `wikiLink` function

Comment: That make sense

Answer (score 0):

In your wikiLink, it looks like you are trying to use the `=>` arrow function shortcut?

You are missing something in your wikiLink function. you either do something like

`function wikilink (Data) {//rest of your code}`

or what the above answer said.